# How do you jump to a particular line when using less from the command line?

Tags: less

I want something like:

`less -j 4567 file.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the man [page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less),

`less +4567 file.txt`

will do what you want.